# Is curly brace optional in lwc import statement

Tags: lightning-web-components

Below is my JS code in LWC:

```
import searchBears from '@salesforce/apex/BearController.searchBears';
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
```

I would like to understand why some import statements are having curly braces and some are not. I tried to refer to the document but not succeeded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on whether the export function is written as default or named exports. I suggest doing a read on default vs named exports on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Suggest also reading this answer to understand in [depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823192/what-is-the-difference-between-with-and-without-curly-bracket-notation-in-export).

An example that does not curly bracket will be as below

```
class Myclass {...};
export default Myclass;
```

The import statement would be as below

```
import Myclass from './src/index.js'
```

**With curly braces**

```
class Myclass {...};
export Myclass;
```

The import would be as below

```
import {Myclass} from './src/index.js'
```

If you view your type definition (under `.sfdx/typings/lwc/apex` folder ) in your vscode you should see something like below where you see export default statement

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mohith for the description. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the default export, you must **not** use curly braces. If you are not using the default export, you **must** use curly braces. They are not optional, but instead reflect if you are importing the default export or not. For example, the following is invalid:

```
import { myMethod } from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.myMethod';
```

As well as:

```
import LightningElement from 'lwc';
```

Both will result in errors. You must consult the documentation or source code (for custom exports) to determine if curly braces are required or restricted.

Comment: The other alternative is typings file under the vscode typings folder under .sfdx folder

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for the description. It's really helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If a default export is used in the class you want to access, eg

```
export default yourthing
```

Then you don't need braces.

If the ES6 export is explicit, you do.

An explicit export looks like:

```
function add( a, b ) {
  return a + b;
}
function sayhi( name ){
  return `Hi ${name}`;
}
export { add, sayhi };
```

In this case, you would need to import these like:

```
import { add, sayhi } from '/mymodule';
```

Or if you only wanted part of the code:

```
import { add } from '/mymodule'
```

Comment: Thanks Caspar for the description. It's really helpful.